# JNDI lookup failure to the remote session bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jndi

Currently I am creating enterprise application client which is supposed to trigger session bean to send messages to the topic. This code was created all according  j2ee-6 documentation [JMS application with session bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgw.html). Unfortunately, it does not work and I could not find the bug. 1. source code is in EA client project, 2. in Java Class Library project and 3,4. in EJB Module project. 1. project has dependencies in libraries to 2. and 3.

Enterprise Application Client:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

/**
 *
 * @author Tomasz Półgrabia <tpsa.s.a@gmail.com>
 */
public class JMSClient {


  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */

  @EJB
  static private PublisherBeanRemote publisherBeanRemote;  

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    publisherBeanRemote.publishNews();
    publisherBeanRemote.publishNews();
  }
}
```

Remote interface:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

/**
 *
 * @author Tomasz Półgrabia <tpsa.s.a@gmail.com>
 */
@Remote
public interface PublisherBeanRemote {

  void publishNews();

  String chooseType();
}
```

PublisherBean

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicPublisher;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Tomasz Półgrabia <tpsa.s.a@gmail.com>
 */
@Stateless
@Remote(PublisherBeanRemote.class)
public class PublisherBean implements PublisherBeanRemote {

  @Resource
  private SessionContext sc;
  @Resource(lookup = "TopicConnectionFactory")
  private TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory;
  @Resource(lookup = "JMSTopic")
  private Topic topic;
  private TopicConnection topicConnection;
  final static String messageTypes[] = {"Nation/World",
    "Metro/Region", "Business", "Sports", "Living/Arts",
    "Opinion"};

  @Override
  public void publishNews() {
    TopicSession topicSession = null;
    TopicPublisher topicPublisher;
    TextMessage textMessage;
    int numMsgs = messageTypes.length * 3;
    String messageType;
    try {
      topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(true, 0);
      topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
      textMessage = topicSession.createTextMessage();

      for (int i = 0; i < numMsgs; i++) {
        messageType = chooseType();
        textMessage.setStringProperty("NewsType", messageType);
        textMessage.setText("Item " + i + ": " + messageType);
        System.out.println("PUBLISHER: Setting "
                + "message text to: " + textMessage.getText());
        topicPublisher.publish(textMessage);
      }

    } catch (JMSException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(PublisherBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
              ex);
      sc.setRollbackOnly();
    } finally {
      if (topicSession != null) {
        try {
          topicSession.close();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(PublisherBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                  null, ex);
        }
      }
    }



  }

  @Override
  public String chooseType() {
    return messageTypes[new Random().nextInt(messageTypes.length)];
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void ejbCreate() {
    try {
      topicConnection = (TopicConnection) topicConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(PublisherBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
              ex);
    }
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void ejbRemove() {
    if (topicConnection != null) {
      try {
        topicConnection.close();
      } catch (JMSException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PublisherBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

MessageBean:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author Tomasz Półgrabia <tpsa.s.a@gmail.com>
 */
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability",
          propertyValue = "durable"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector",
          propertyValue = "NewsType = 'Sports' OR NewsType = 'Opinion'"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup",
          propertyValue = "TopicConnectionFactory"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId",
          propertyValue = "JMSTopic"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName",
          propertyValue = "MySub"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup",
          propertyValue = "JMSTopic"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
          propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic")
})
public class MessageBean implements MessageListener {

  public MessageBean() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
    TextMessage txtMsg;
    if (inMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
      try {
        txtMsg = (TextMessage) inMessage;
        System.out.println("Got message: " + txtMsg.getText());
      } catch (JMSException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MessageBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    } else {
      System.err.println("Message in wrong type: "
              + inMessage.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Deploy:

```
ant -f F:\\Documents\\projekty\\JMSClient2 -DforceRedeploy=false run
init:
JMSBean.init:
JMSClassLibrary.init:
Deleting: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClassLibrary\build\built-jar.properties
JMSClassLibrary.deps-jar:
Updating property file: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClassLibrary\build\built-jar.properties
JMSClassLibrary.compile:
JMSClassLibrary.jar:
JMSBean.deps-jar:
Compiling 1 source file to F:\Documents\projekty\JMSBean\build\classes
JMSBean.compile:
JMSBean.library-inclusion-in-archive:
Building jar: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSBean\dist\JMSBean.jar
JMSBean.dist:
JMSClassLibrary.init:
Deleting: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClassLibrary\build\built-jar.properties
JMSClassLibrary.deps-jar:
Updating property file: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClassLibrary\build\built-jar.properties
JMSClassLibrary.compile:
JMSClassLibrary.jar:
deps-jar:
compile:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
Building jar: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClient2\dist\JMSClient2.jar
dist:
pre-run-deploy:
Redeploying F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClient2\dist\JMSClient2.jar
Initializing...
post-run-deploy:
run-deploy:
Copying 1 file to F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClient2\dist
Copying 2 files to F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClient2\dist\JMSClient2Client
Warning: F:\Documents\projekty\JMSClient2\dist\gfdeploy\JMSClient2 does not exist.
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.JMSClient/publisherBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote,refType=Session into class pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.JMSClient: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.JMSClient/publisherBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:204)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer$ClientMainClassSetting.getClientMainClass(AppClientContainer.java:636)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.getMainMethod(AppClientContainer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.completePreparation(AppClientContainer.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.prepare(AppClientContainer.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.JMSClient/publisherBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.JMSClient/publisherBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.JMSClient/publisherBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote#pl.polgrabiat.jmsbean.PublisherBeanRemote not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Java Result: 1
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 38 seconds)
```